# javascript function can't recognize variable in same document

Tags: javascript, html, variables, ejs

I need some Directions for basic Javascript problem.

I'm making an ejs page to show user information.

1. When I load this page, I get 'userList' data as array. then I put them into vUserList array 
   for future use. and when function 'showUserInfo' is called, I put the information into documents.

I have two problem.

When I used for loop and function in same  tag, the function didn't work at all. 
When I split for loop and function into different  tag, both works but function can't recognize
the vUserList array.

How can I let function recognize the Array variable?

Here is my code for the page.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var vUserList = new Array();
        <% for (var i = 0; i < userList.length ; i++) { %>
            vUserList[<%=i %>] = new Array();
            vUserList[<%=i %>].googleUid = <%=userList[i].googleUid %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].googleName = <%=userList[i].googleName %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].memberUid = "<%=userList[i].memberUid %>";
            vUserList[<%=i %>].clientVersion = <%=userList[i].clientVersion %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].deviceId = <%=userList[i].deviceId %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].ticket = <%=userList[i].ticket %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].joinTime = <%=userList[i].joinTime %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].loginTime = <%=userList[i].loginTime %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].feni = <%=userList[i].feni %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].fuel = <%=userList[i].fuel %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].itemAttackCount = <%=userList[i].itemAttackCount %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].lastStation = <%=userList[i].lastStation %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].clearCount = <%=userList[i].clearCount %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].playLevel = <%=userList[i].playLevel %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].tutorial = <%=userList[i].tutorial %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].fuelChargeTime = <%=userList[i].fuelChargeTime %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].fuelTime = <%=userList[i].fuelTime %>;
            vUserList[<%=i %>].level = new Array();
            vUserList[<%=i %>].level = <%=userList[i].level %>;
        <% } %>
    </script>

    <script>
        function showUserInfo(idx) {
            alert(vUserList[0].memberUid);
            document.getElementById("googleUid").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].googleUid;
            document.getElementById("googleName").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].googleName;
            document.getElementById("memberUid").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].memberUid;
            document.getElementById("clientVersion").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].clientVersion;
            document.getElementById("deviceId").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].deviceId;
            document.getElementById("ticket").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].ticket;
            document.getElementById("joinTime").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].joinTime;
            document.getElementById("loginTime").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].loginTime;
            document.getElementById("feni").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].feni;
            document.getElementById("fuel").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].fuel;
            document.getElementById("itemAttackCount").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].itemAttackCount;
            document.getElementById("lastStation").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].lastStation;
            document.getElementById("clearCount").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].clearCount;
            document.getElementById("playLevel").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].playLevel;
            document.getElementById("tutorial").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].tutorial;
            document.getElementById("fuelChargeTime").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].fuelChargeTime;
            document.getElementById("fuelTime").innerHTML=vUserList[idx].fuelTime;
        }
    </script>



</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <% include menubar.ejs %>
    </div>
    <div id="userList" vertical-align=bottom align=left>
        Here will be UserList from DB<br>
        <form method="post" action="/getUserList">
            memberUid<input type="text" name="memberUid"><br>
            LastStation<input type="text" name="startStation">~<input type="text" name="endStation"><br>
            Number of List <select name="limitNum">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                    </select><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
        <% if (userList != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) { %>
                <a href="#" onclick="showUserInfo(<%= i %>); return false;"><%= userList[i].memberUid %></a> <br>
                <% console.log(userList[i].memberUid) %>
        <% } } %>

    </div>
    <div align=center vertical-align=bottom>
        user Information. <br>
        googleUid : <p id="googleUid"></p>
        googleName : <p id="googleName"></p>
        memberUid : <p id="memberUid"></p>
        clientVersion : <p id="clientVersion"></p>
        deviceId : <p id="deviceId"></p>
        ticket : <p id="ticket"></p>
        joinTime : <p id="joinTime"></p>
        loginTime : <p id="loginTime"></p>
        feni : <p id="feni"></p>
        fuel : <p id="fuel"></p>
        itemAttackCount : <p id="itemAttackCount"></p>
        lastStation : <p id="lastStation"></p>
        clearCount : <p id="clearCount"></p>
        playLevel : <p id="playLevel"></p>
        tutorial : <p id="tutorial"></p>
        fuelChargeTime : <p id="fuelChargeTime"></p>
        fuelTime : <p id="fuelTime"></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the generated markup look like (please keep it minimal)?

Answer (score 0):

The variable vUserList is not in the scope of the function showUserInfo. You will have to declare(the var step) the variable in the scope of the function since javascript uses function level scope. You must to put all the code in a single script tag. Figure out why that is not working. I think it is just a formatting issue. And put the variable inside the showUserInfo Function.

A dirty hack might work for you though. Remove the word 'var' from the declaration of vUserList. It will then pollute the global name space. But you should be able to access it from anywhere in the window. I would not suggest you to go down this road, nevertheless.

Comment: "*You **need** to put all the code in a single script tag*". Good suggestion, but "should" rather than "need".

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment (needed space), some suggestions

In the first loop you are doing:

```
var vUserList = new Array();
<% for (var i = 0; i < userList.length ; i++) { %>
    vUserList[<%=i %>] = new Array();
    vUserList[<%=i %>].googleUid = <%=userList[i].googleUid %>;
    vUserList[<%=i %>].googleName = <%=userList[i].googleName %>;
    ...
```

This assigns an Array to *vUserList[i]*, then treats it like an Object. That works because Arrays are Objects, but it's not using any of the Array goodness, so you should be using an Object, and it's considered cleaner to use a literal rather than call the constructor, so:

```
  vUserList[<%=i %>] = {};
  ...
```

To make things a little more concise, you could use a literal like:

```
    vUserList[<%=i %>] = { googleUid: <%=userList[i].googleUid %>,
                           googleName: <%=userList[i].googleName %,
                           ...
                           fuelTime: <%=userList[i].fuelTime %>,
                           level: [<%=userList[i].level %>]
                          };
```

Also, consider using a loop and data array for the *showUserInfo* function:

```
function showUserInfo(idx) {
  var userData = ['googleUid','googleName','memberUid','clientVersion','deviceId',
    'ticket','joinTime','loginTime','feni','fuel','itemAttackCount','lastStation',
    'clearCount','playLevel','tutorial','fuelChargeTime','fuelTime'];

  userData.forEach(function(v) {
    document.getElementById(v).innerHTML = vUserList[idx][v];
  });
}
```

You could apply a similar strategy to the first loop.

HTH. ;-)